# Bulkifying Code For a Callout

Tags: apex, callout, bulkification

I have a trigger on EmailMessage. I have to get the subject of the case created from the email message. From the subject I am calling an APi to get the language and then updating it to the case object.

I am not able to bulkify the code in proper manner due to @future method. Please suggest.

```
trigger Trg_DetectLanguage on EmailMessage (after insert) {
         Set<Id> messageIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();

            Map<Id, Case> mapCases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id IN : messageIds )]);

            List<case> caseList = new List<case>();

            for ( EmailMessage message : trigger.new) {
                Case caseObj = mapCases.get(message.ParentId);    

                Cls_DetectLanguage.getLanguages(caseObj.subject);
                caseList.add(Cls_DetectLanguage.createCaseObjForUpdate(caseObj));
            }

            Cls_DetectLanguage.updateCaseList(caseList);

        }


public Class Cls_DetectLanguage
{
   Static String language;   

   @future (callout = true)
   public Static void getLanguages(String subject) {    
      String languageCode; 
   // languageCode = executeAPI(subject);
      language = getLanguageNameFromCode(languageCode);
     //return language;
   }

   public static void updateCaseList( List<Case> caseList)
   {
     update caseList;
   }

   public Static Case createCaseObjForUpdate(Case caseObj)
   {
       caseObj.Case_Language__c = language;
       caseObj.Origin ='Email';
       caseObj.Status='New';

       return caseObj;
   }

   public Static String executeAPI(String subject)
   {
     String languageCode ;
         HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
         HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
         Http http = new Http();

         DetectLanguage__c Obj = DetectLanguage__c.getValues('DS1') ;
         String key = Obj.Key__c;
      // String searchField = Obj.SearchField__c;

       // String content = '{"q":"' + 'caseObj.' + searchField  + '", "key":"' + key  + '"}';
       // String content = '{"q":"' + caseObj.Subject + '", "key":"' + key  + '"}';        

          String content = '{"q":"' + subject + '", "key":"' + key  + '"}';    
          req.SetEndpoint('https://lang.com/0.2/detect');         
          req.SetBody(content);
          req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
          req.setMethod('POST');
          System.Debug('Language Call');
          req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

        try {
             res = http.send(req);

             JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

             while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                    (parser.getText() == 'language')) {
                    parser.nextToken();
                     languageCode = parser.getText(); 
               }
             }
           } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
                    System.debug('Callout error: '+ e); 
          }
       return languageCode; 
   }

   public static String getLanguageNameFromCode(String languageCode)
   {
     String supportedLang;
     for( Supported_Languages__c supportedLanguage :([Select Name from Supported_Languages__c where Language_Code__c =: languageCode]))
       supportedLang = supportedLanguage.Name;
          return supportedLang ;
   }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: @ChristianDeckert - this relates to future method bulkification and is not addressed in the link you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the Set of message Ids into the future method where the callout will be made. From there you will be able to update the Case records subject fields as required.

You should avoid making a callout per record in the set. This will break on the callout limit when there are more than 10 message Ids in the set.